# Updating a nested objects in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following express route:

```
const updateSnapshot = async (req, res) => {
    const accountId = req.body.account_id;

    if (!accountId) {
        return fail(res, 'account id is missing', 400);
    }

    try {
        const account = await Account
            .findOne({ _id: accountId})
            .populate({
                path: 'snapshot',
                model: 'Snapshot'
            });
        // I want to update these fields in snapshot
        const snapshot = {
          friends_count: data.friends_count,
          updated_date: new Date() 
        };


       account.snapshot.friends_count = snapshot.friends_count;
       account.snapshot.updated_date = snapshot.updated_date;

       await account.save();

      return success(res, snapshot);
    } catch(error) {
        fail(res, error.message, 500);
    }
};
```

I want to update the nested object `snapshot` (just the fields `friends_count` and `update_date`) however when I check the database it seems to have not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateSnapshot = (req, res) => {
    const accountId = req.body.account_id;

    if (!accountId) {
        return fail(res, 'account id is missing', 400);
    };

    Account
        .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: accountId }, {
            $set: {
                snapshot: {
                    friends_count: data.friends_count,
                    updated_date: new Date()
                }
            }
        }, {
            new: true
        })
        .then(account => {
            if(!account) {
                return fail(res, "Account not found", 404);
            } else {
                return success(res, account);
            };
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return fail(res, error.message, 500);
        });
};
```

Here we're using the `findOneAndUpdate` method and promises to find and update the document in one operation.

`findOneAndUpdate` takes the query criteria as the first parameter, the second parameter updates values specified in the object (we're using the `$set` operator to update specific values of the `snapshot` object), and the three parameter is an object that defines the operation's `options` (`new` is set to true to return the newly updated object).

**Note**: $set will replace the entire snapshot object so if there are other properties inside the snapshot object, they will need to be included inside the `$set` object.

Comment: Seem to be getting the following error with the code above:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
  friends_count: 2,  updated_date: '2020-09-04T05:24:37.082Z'
}" at path "snapshot"

Comment: Also you wrote "we're using the $set operator to update specific values of the snapshot object" but then ": $set will replace the entire snapshot". I'm confused now. I only want to update those specific values.

Comment: Looking at your original code, you're populating the snapshot from the Snapshot model, so I'm assuming that the snapshot object isn't originally defined in your Accounts model?

Comment: And sorry for the confusion, the `$set` operator adds a new object to the document or replaces the specified object if it already exists. You can read more at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/.